# Image not working

Tags: html, css, image

When I put the image inside nav it works but when I put it in body or header it doesn't.  I have the image tag right because when I put it in nav it works.  I know this code is unscientific but I'm new to html.  Thanks for the help in advanced.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Random Site </title>
        <style type = 'text/css'>
        header nav {
            float: right;
            background-color: gray;
            width: 100%;
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            right:0px;
            height: 60px;
        }
        header nav a {
            font-size: 120%;
            float: right;
            padding: 1%;
            font-family: 'Helvetica';
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
            position: relative;
            top: 5px
        }

        header nav a:hover {
            color: white;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src = 'image.jpg' alt= 'image' width= '100px' height= '70px'/>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <a href = 'www.google.com'> games </a>
                <a href = 'www.google.com'> about </a>
                <a href = 'www.google.com'> contact </a>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working but you just aren't seeing it because you have the nav positioned absolute so I think it's just overlapping your image. Try giving your image a class then do something like this:

```
.myimage { position: relative; z-index: 2; }
```

Comment: Thanks, even after I fixed it that was still very helpful.  I would vote up but I can't sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I forgot to put the ; after top 5px.  Sorry about that.